# How to convert Wordpress post_content into Laravel view?

Tags: php, laravel-4, wordpress

I've been using Laravel for all my application development but have recently found Wordpress really great at bootstrapping high quality views through the multitude of amazing themes, widgets, and customization options.

Having Laravel and Wordpress work side-by-side has been simple to setup thanks to the excellent guide @ http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/

The question is how to hook into WP's HTML/CSS/Js generation functions so I can bring the content back into a Laravel view by post_id. Here's the typical data I would want to convert:

```
post_content = <code>[fullwidth backgroundcolor="" backgroundimage="" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat"]          </code>
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px !important;">Test test<span       style="color: #e9a825;"> #1 </span>testing testing</h1>
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 17px !important;">With over [tooltip   title="Stack Overflow is awesome"]<strong>yeah!</strong>[/tooltip]more [tooltip title="abc"]<strong>test</strong>  [/tooltip] test.</p>
[/fullwidth]
```

The goal is to do all the generation internally in Laravel if possible since ideally I'd like to inject custom data from my Laravel app into the queried post content before generating the HTML/CSS/JS that I would then pass onto my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me. I added this code to my BaseController.
Use as follows:

```
echo $this->_get_wp_post(123);

public function _get_wp_post($post_id) {
    ob_start();
    get_header();
    $header = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_start();         
    $content = '';
    global $post;
    $post  = get_post($post_id);
    setup_postdata($post);
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_start();
    get_footer();
    $footer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $header . $content . $footer;
}
```

A caveat: some tweaking might be required for certain elements from custom themes to work as expected and/or to eliminate Laravel exceptions.

Hope this is helpful to somebody.